# Why are p-values from the binomial test in R non-monotonic in trials?

Tags: r, p-value, binomial-distribution

The R function `binom.test` performs an exact binomial test. In trying to understand how many trails would be necessary to reject the null given *zero* successes, I plotted the p-value as follows

```
p <- 1/16
n <- seq(2,200)
pval <- lapply(n, function(x) binom.test(0,x,p)$p.value)
plot(n, pval)
```

[image: plot of pval vs n]

I was surprised to see that the p-value did not decrease monotonically with increasing trials. What is the reason for this and is it accurate?

Comment: It is because the binomial random variable is discrete. See my paper in the American Statistician coauthored with Christine Liu.  "The Saw-toothed Behavior of Power vs Sample Size and Software Solutions: Single Binomial Proportions using Exact Methods. American Statistician (2002) Vol. 56 pp 149-155.

Comment: I took @StephanKolassa advice. I realize that the result is counter-intuitive and it may take more detailed accounts in the references to get a clear picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because the binomial random variable is discrete. My paper in *The American Statistician* [1] explains this and gives other references. Think about the fact that the planned type 1 error cannot be achieved exactly for all values of the sample size n.

[1]  Michael R Chernick & Christine Y Liu (2012). The Saw-Toothed Behavior of Power Versus Sample Size and Software Solutions. *The American Statistician*, 56:2, 149-155, DOI: [10.1198/000313002317572835](https://doi.org/10.1198/000313002317572835)